# How get list from firebase at once?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have array of keys and I want to get objects with this keys from other list  of object from firebase. How it looks now. I passed list of indexes as parameter to the method in service and there through loop I'm getting every object and push it to array, which read in the controller. But, I think it looks ugly. How I can get all objects from firebase at once time, without foreach and calling $apply() afterwards? I simplified it a little, but I think idea is clear. 
Thanks

Factory

```
(function() {
    angular.module("app").factory('app.factory', appFactory);

    appFactory.$inject = ['$rootScope']

function appFactory($rootScope) {
 self.loadList = function(list) {
    self.ListingData = [];
    angular.forEach(list, function(val, key) {
        db.child('listings').child(key).once('value').then(function(product) {
            var value = product.val();
            $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                self.ListingData.push(value);
            });
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

    });

};

    return self;


    }
})();
```

Controller

```
(function() {
angular.module("app").controller('app.Ctrl', appCtrl);

appCtrl.$inject = ['app.factory', '$scope'];


function listingsCtrl(appFactory, $scope) {

    $scope.loadListing = function(list) {

        listingsFactory.loadList(list);
        $scope.list = listingsFactory.ListingData;

    }

    // load list by default
    $scope.loadListing(list);

    }
})();
```

Comment: might take a look at angularFire to make it much easier

Answer (score 0):

Using `Promise.all` and `map` might make things a little easier:

```
self.loadList = function (list) {

  var getListings = list.map(function (val, key) {
    return db.child('listings').child(key).once('value');
  });

  Promise.all(getListings)
    .then(function (products) {
      self.ListingData = products.map(function (product) {
        return product.val();
      });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```